# Windows drivers: Scatter gather win32

Tags: wdk, scatter

Is it possible to do scatter gather via DeviceIOControl  function?
Writing a scatter gather function to read and write.

Any idea if ReadFile Scatter and WriteFilescatter work?

Answer (score 0):

why wouldn't it work?  As far as the OS considered it works. underlying hw/driver must  be able to handle the S/G blocks and unify them into a single unit (or split to many for read operation) - but that's not something in scope of OS but rather a specific device and its software.